# Upload File Error in CodeIgniter and angularjs

Tags: php, angularjs, codeigniter

I want to upload file to the codeigniter restapi server but the server show error when uploading file, its shows "Illegal offset type in isset or empty", here the code..

userpass.page.ts

```
  onChange(event){
    const img = event.target.files;
    this.data.img = img.item(0); 
    alert(this.data.img);
  }

  async onSubmit(data){
    console.warn(data);
    const loading = await this.loadingController.create({
      message: 'Please wait...',
      duration: 1000
    });
    loading.present();
   
    this.users.updateusers(this.data).subscribe( async result => {
     // await console.log(result);
      loading.dismiss();
      alert("Berhasil Update");
    },error=>{
      alert("Terjadi Kesalahan");
    })
  }
```

userpass.page.html

```
<form #userform="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(userform.value)" *ngFor="let item of items">
          <input type="hidden" name="ID" #id="ngModel" required [ngModel]="data.id" />
          <ion-item>
            <ion-label position="stacked">Username</ion-label>
            <ion-input #username="ngModel" placeholder="Ganti Username" name="Username" required [ngModel]="data.user"></ion-input>
          </ion-item>
          <span *ngIf="username.invalid && username.touched" class="error">Username Is Require</span>
          <ion-item>
            <ion-label position="stacked">Nama</ion-label>
            <ion-input #nama="ngModel" placeholder="Ganti Nama" name="Nama" required [ngModel]="data.name"></ion-input>
          </ion-item>
          <ion-item>
            <ion-label position="stacked">Password</ion-label>
            <ion-input #password="ngModel" type="password" minlength="6"
            placeholder="Ganti Password" name="Password" required [ngModel]="data.pass" ></ion-input>
          </ion-item>
          <ion-item>
            <ion-label position="stacked">Tanda Tangan Digital</ion-label>
            <ion-input type="File" name="img" (change)="onChange($event)"></ion-input>
          </ion-item>
          <span *ngIf="password.invalid && password.touched" class="error">Password is Require</span>
          <ion-button [disabled]="username.invalid || nama.invalid || password.invalid" type="submit">Submit</ion-button>
</form>
```

RestApi Users.php

```
$ID_USER = $this->post('ID');
$data = array(
   'Nama'     => $this->post('Nama'),
   'username'   => $this->post('Username'),
   'password'    => $this->post('Password')
);
if($this->post('img')!=''){
                $img = $this->post('img');
                $config['upload_path']="./";
                $config['allowed_types']='gif|jpg|png';
                $config['max_size'] = '0';
                $config['max_filename'] = '255'; 
                $this->load->library('upload', $config);
                if($this->upload->do_upload($img)) {
                } else {
                }
}
            $this->db->where('IDusers', $ID_USER );
            $update = $this->db->update('users', $data);
if ($update) {
                $this->response($_POST);
                //$this->response(array('status'=> 'berhasil', 200));
} else {
                $this->response(array('status'=> 'fail', 502));
}
```

Console Log Respond

```
<div style="border:1px solid #990000;padding-left:20px;margin:0 0 10px 0;">

<h4>A PHP Error was encountered</h4>

<p>Severity: Warning</p>
<p>Message:  Illegal offset type in isset or empty</p>
<p>Filename: libraries/Upload.php</p>
<p>Line Number: 377</p>
    <p>Backtrace:</p>
            <p style="margin-left:10px">
            File: C:\xampp\htdocs\balifoamapi\application\controllers\api\Users.php<br />
            Line: 48<br />
            Function: do_upload         </p>
            <p style="margin-left:10px">
            File: C:\xampp\htdocs\balifoamapi\application\libraries\REST_Controller.php<br />
            Line: 785<br />
            Function: call_user_func_array          </p>
            <p style="margin-left:10px">
            File: C:\xampp\htdocs\balifoamapi\index.php<br />
            Line: 315<br />
            Function: require_once          </p>
</div>
<div style="border:1px solid #990000;padding-left:20px;margin:0 0 10px 0;">

<h4>A PHP Error was encountered</h4>

<p>Severity: Warning</p>
<p>Message:  preg_match_all() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given</p>
<p>Filename: libraries/Upload.php</p>
<p>Line Number: 382</p>
    <p>Backtrace:</p>
            <p style="margin-left:10px">
            File: C:\xampp\htdocs\balifoamapi\application\controllers\api\Users.php<br />
            Line: 48<br />
            Function: do_upload         </p>

            <p style="margin-left:10px">
            File: C:\xampp\htdocs\balifoamapi\application\libraries\REST_Controller.php<br />
            Line: 785<br />
            Function: call_user_func_array          </p>

            <p style="margin-left:10px">
            File: C:\xampp\htdocs\balifoamapi\index.php<br />
            Line: 315<br />
            Function: require_once          </p>
</div>[]
```

How to solve this and make the file uploaded successfully into the server ?
Thank you in advance and sorry about the code

Comment: You didn't include the code where it says "Illegal offset type in isset or empty", we need to see this

Comment: @EyadMohammedOsama Edited, I'm so sorry. I forgot to add that